# check the selected value in drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following drop down list. How can I check the selected value BEFORE saving the data into the module? I want to use the selected value in setting the values of Neighborhood's drop down list.

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City, new SelectList(
          new List<Object>{
               new { value = "Abha", text = "Abha" },
               new { value = "Al Qunfudhah", text = "Al Qunfudhah" },
               new { value = "Al-Kharj", text = "Al-Kharj" },
               new { value = "Al-Ahsa", text = "Al-Ahsa" },
               new { value = "Buraidah", text = "Buraidah" },
               new { value = "Dammam", text = "Dammam" },
               new { value = "Ha'il", text = "Ha'il"},
               new { value = "Hafar Al-Batin", text = "Hafar Al-Batin" },
               new { value = "Jazan", text = "Jazan" },
               new { value = "Jeddah", text = "Jeddah" },
               new { value = "Jubail", text = "Jubail" },
               new { value = "khobar", text = "khobar" },
               new { value = "Khamis Mushait", text = "Khamis Mushait" },
               new { value = "Mecca", text = "Mecca" },
               new { value = "Medina", text = "Medina" },
               new { value = "Najran", text = "Najran" },
               new { value = "Qatif", text = "Qatif" },
               new { value = "Riyadh", text = "Riyadh" },
               new { value = "Tabuk", text = "Tabuk" },
               new { value = "Ta'if", text = "Ta'if" },
               new { value = "Yanbu", text = "Yanbu" }
          },"value", "text", "Jeddah"))

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the value of property `City` is (say) "Al-Kharj" then the 3rd option will be selected - you need to set the value in the controller before you pass the model to the view (and setting the last parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is pointless - your binding to a property). And you can simplify it to just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(new List<string>() {"Abha", "Al Qunfudhah", ...."Yanbu"})`

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can try

```
$('#City').val();
```

If you are not using jQuery, the vanilla javascript way would be

```
var element = document.getElementById("City");
var strVal = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```